# Topological space, manifold, open sets

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Consider a homeomorphism $f$ sending an open set $X$ of one manifold to an open set $Y$ of another manifold:
$$
f\,:~X \longrightarrow Y~~.
$$
Being a homeomorphism, $f$ is continuous -- and so is its inverse $g = f^{-1}~$:
$$
g\,:~   Y\longrightarrow X ~~.
$$

Then a (not necessarily open) subset
$$
A \subset X 
$$
is mapped by $f$ to a (not necessarily open) subset $f A\subset Y$.

The resulting restrictions of $f$ and $g = f^{-1}$ are:

$$
f_{~|A}\,: ~~~~ A \longrightarrow f(A)~~,
$$
$$
g_{~|f(A)}\,: ~~~ f(A) \longrightarrow A  ~~.
$$

Now, if I postulate that the image $f(A)~$ ${\underline{\mbox{is}}}$ open, will that imply that the preimage $A$ is open also?

Stated shortly: is a restriction of a continuous map continuous too?

/It certainly is in calculus -- but how to show this in topology?/

Comment: The restriction of a homeomorphism is also a homeomorphism, isn't it?

Comment: @NDewolf Can you kindly prove it to me? Saying that a restriction of a continuous function is continuous is simply a reformulation of my question in different words. Why is the restriction continuous?

Comment: @NDewolf I think I now understand where and why I got stuck. I failed to postulate that $A$ should be endowed with the subspace topology. With this detail added, things become clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism and $A\subseteq X$, then $f_{|A}:A\to f(A)$ is a homeomorphism as well. Regardless of what $A$ is, open or not.

Indeed, being a homeomorphism means that there is a continuous inverse $g:Y\to X$. Now a restriction of continuous function is continuous and so $f_{|A}$ is continuous. Obviously $g_{|f(A)}:f(A)\to A$ is well defined (because $g(f(A))=A$) and continuous as well. This $g_{|f(A)}$ is the inverse of $f_{|A}$.

Comment: Dear @freakish , thank you for your answer. 

I am afraid, you have simply reformulated my question in different words. I enquired if, for an open $f(A)$, the set $A$ should come out open -- and you responded that it should because  $f_{|A}$ is continuous.  But these are just two formulations of the same fact. Why is this fact correct?  

Can you please explain me why $f_{|A}$ is also continuous? 

(I know that a restriction of a continuous function is continuous in calculus. Why also in topology?)

Comment: Dear @freakish , I have now understood where my difficulties came from. I forgot to postulate that $A$ must be equipped with a subspace topology. With that convention enacted, all becomes simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got it now, thanks to @NDewolf and @freakish.

In my question, one detail was missing: I forgot to say that $A$ is given the subspace topology. With this detail added, the answer should look like this:

If $f$ is continuous, this means that for any open $f(A)$ its preimage $A$ must be open.

Specifically, the restriction $f_{|A}$ is continuous *given that $A$ is given the subspace topology*.